# I want to download bs4 but it doesn't work

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZl6Z.png) can you help me?

it always gives this error i want to download bs4 but it gives this error i will go crazy soon please help. I tried !pip install BS4 and &pip install BS4 and pip install BS4 and install BS4 but without success please help.

Comment: Please, don't use image to represent text/code... just do a classic _copy-paste_!

Comment: Why are you installing it from a system call inside of python code?  Just type `pip install bs4` at a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

just try to install it from your terminal and if there is an error just copy and paste the error here dont use image plaese

```
pip install bs4 # in your terminal
```